# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm facing this error when writing a test for a directive (using `generator-angular-module`):

**src/capitalize.js:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jviotti.string', []).filter('capitalize', function() {

  return function(input) {
    return input.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
  };

});
```

**test/spec/capitalize.js:**

```
'use strict';

describe('Filter: capitalize', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('jviotti.string'));

  var capitalize;
  beforeEach(inject(function($filter) {
    capitalize = $filter('capitalize');
  }));

  it('should capitalize a string', function () {
    expect(capitalize('hello')).toBe('Hello');
  });

});
```

However, when running Karma with PhantomJS I get:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X) Filter: capitalize should capitalize a string FAILED
    TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
        at workFn (/Users/jviotti/Projects/angular-string/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2107)
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'capitalize('hello')')
        at /Users/jviotti/Projects/angular-string/test/spec/capitalize.js:14
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.1 secs / 0.017 secs)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've been having errors like this since 1.2.0 update, it usually was a typo or a missing file in karma.conf... are you including all the files in correct order in karma? (can you add the files array to the question?)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change in karma.conf.js

```
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
```

to

```
  logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
```

and PhantomJS to Firefox, then You will get more verbose error message

Comment: This helped me troubleshoot a similar issue (same error message but I I'm testing a controller not a directive).  In my case the name I used in $controller(...) didn't match up with an actual controller name in my application.

Comment: I get `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: capitalizeFilterProvider <- capitalizeFilter`. Why is trying to inject `capitalizeFilter`, when I using `$filter('capitalize')`?

Comment: @jviotti, the name of the filter and the injection is ok, the `Filter` suffix is added by angular in the error message. See my comment in your question, are you adding the js file where the filter is declared to the karma files array?

Comment: Yes it's added, however another filter in the same module was defining  `angular.module('jviotti.string', [])`. Deleting that file makes the test pass

Comment: This also helped me. I initially overlooked "PhantomJS to Firefox" part and wasn't helpful but once I changed it to "Firefox" it gives me an error exactly what I missed.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to this (in Angular 1.2.2) is commenting out line 2107 inthe angular-mocks.js file:

```
if(e.stack && errorForStack) e.stack +=  '\n' + errorForStack.stack;
```

Apparently in PhantomJS the error stack is readonly.

Edit:

This error shouldn't occur any more in Angular 1.2.10+ ([github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047)) (Thanks sherlocken!)

Comment: It seems there was a bug with respect to Phantomjs and certain other browsers.  Fix merged into v 1.2.10. see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047 and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7e916455b36dc9ca4d4afc1e44cade90006d00e3.

Answer (score 2):

I am also seeing this issue in v1.2.5. It appears to be a regression in angular-mocks.js: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047

You can manually patch angular-mocks.js from this diff: https://github.com/wizardwerdna/angular.js/commit/17515763b891ea617339610fe92079cefe0efbbe

Comment: and merge commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7e916455b36dc9ca4d4afc1e44cade90006d00e3

Answer (score 2):

May be helped by upgrading to at least 1.2.10, which merges an issue with respect to PhantomJS and certain other browsers.  See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5047 and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/v1.2.10.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added references js files at the top of your spec like below

```
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" /> 
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" />
```

NOTE: angular-mocks.js must be after angular.js and before your test files